# was unable to load a nib named "TwitterDrilldownView"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] was unable to load a nib named "TwitterDrilldownView"
```

I get the above error when I push a new ViewController onto the navigation stack. This is the push code,

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[TwitterDrilldownViewController alloc] initWithTwitterAnnotation:temp] autorelease] animated:YES];`

Basically I am just pushing a newly allocated and initialized view onto the stack. The init method of the ViewController is,

```
- (id)initWithTwitterAnnotation:(TwitterInfo *)aPOI {  
  if(self = [super init]) {
    poi = aPOI;
  }

  return self;
}
```

As you can see I do not use any initialize with nib method and there is no nib file named TwitterDrilldownView in my project.

I did have a nib file before I created the TwitterDrilldownViewController called TwitterDrillDownView but I was using it to test a layout and, again, never used it. When I created TwitterDrilldownViewController the TwitterDrillDownView.nib was present in the project and it was after this stage that I deleted the nib.

The only cause for this problem that I can think of is that Xcode somehow created a dependency on the nib file because the nib file and view controller are named the same(TwitterDrilldownView.nib, TwitterDrilldownViewController.m), as if it was trying to be helpful but is ultimately messing up my project.

I have tried deleting and recreating the view controller in the hope that any references will be destroyed, and removed any reference to nib files in the project but to no avail.

Has anyone please got any experience with this problem or know a possible solution?

Comment: having the exact same problem after deleting a NIB - did you ever resolve this one?

Comment: My resolution was to rename the ViewController, unfortunately the only thing I could do. Guess a logged bug with Apple would be a good idea if it's still broken 2+ years later :)

Comment: :) i also found another solution, which i'll note below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also happened to me after deleting a XIB file out of my project. However, I did some messing around and was able to resolve the problem.

The key point is that **Xcode seems to keep some kind of reference** somewhere as you create XIBs and outlets/actions within them, **and deleting a XIB file manually simply orphans these references**. Removing these connections one-by-one, using the interface builder (UB) and the XIB seems to de-reference them properly.

**The solution** is then pretty clear:

1. Re-create a XIB file of the same name and similar construction (including the outlets and actions you had before). (Note: *If you can't remember how to re-construct the XIB's* outlets and actions, just re-create the XIB file with the same name and skip to my 'if it's still failing' note below.)
2. Manually, one-by-one, remove all of the outlets and actions in your XIB using interface builder (IB).
3. Re-build the app; if it works now, you can delete the XIB.

(**Note: If it's still failing**, you will probably have a different error. If the error refers to *key-value compliance* then it will list a method in the error - and that method is your problem. Make sure you recreate the named outlet/action in IB, and remove it manually using IB. That seems to de-reference the call in Xcode/your build environment.)

Happy hunting!

Comment: Great, I'm happy to move this to the accepted answer as you've specified much more useful steps for debugging and fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

UIViewController should be initialized using `initWithNibName:bundle:` method. In its description stated:

> This is the designated initializer for
>   this class.
>
> If you specify nil for the nibName
>   parameter and do not override the
>   loadView method in your custom
>   subclass, the default view controller
>   behavior is to look for a nib file
>   whose name (without the .nib
>   extension) matches the name of your
>   view controller class. If it finds
>   one, the class name becomes the value
>   of the nibName property, which results
>   in the corresponding nib file being
>   associated with this view controller.

So if you do not load you view controller from nib file make sure you override `loadView` method and set controller's `view` property in it.
Hope that will help.

Comment: Great comment and thanks for that info(I didn't know that) but in this case it doesn't apply as I have other View Controllers that are initialized the exact same way, all not requiring any overriding of loadView. The one difference is that I didn't have any nib file for the others so I remain convinced that it must be a bug somewhere in Xcode.

I solved the problem by renaming my TwitterDrilldownViewController slightly and it works now. I can only assume that Xcode does have some incorrect reference to the old nib file and I am still curious if any anyone else has had this issue. Thanks again.

Comment: hm, may be you should unmark my answer as accepted - may be someone will point to real solution to that problem?

Comment: I think your answer is good for this and will help anyone else who has this problem. My specific problem seems to be very obscure so I'll leave it at that.